# JavaFX and printing to Epson printer

Tags: api, javafx, printing, epson, javapos

I need to know the answer of those questions, concerning Epson printers :

1. Can I use `Javafx` `print` API to print to an EPSON printer ? or should I use the `JavaPOS` API ?
2. How do I print Images to that printer ?
3. How to setup page size ?

I have Epson TM-20II printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and experience with an epson printer (the model in the question)

> Can I use Javafx print API to print to an EPSON printer ? or should I
>   use the JavaPOS API ?
>   How do I print Images to that printer ?
>   Any document can be printed using that printer whatever api is used.

Of course. A print api and the one existing in JavaFX can be used to print to that printer.

> How to setup page size ?

A page can be created using a helper method, embedded into JavaFx api, as follows :

```
PrintHelper.createPaper("PapperName", width, height, Units.MM);
```

> `width -> int`
>
> `height -> int`

Answer (score 1):

Use [JasperViewerFX](https://github.com/mgrecol/JasperViewerFx), which is full featured `JasperReport` viewer written completely in `JavaFx`.

Comment: How this can print to epson printers ?

Comment: You have to download and attach that project in your project.

And import documents or you can also modify the code as your need.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know how to use and import libraries into my project. I think my questions are straightforward, you didn't show how your answer relate to my problem.

Comment: Sorry for the gap of communication. I think the type of printer doesn't matter for printing with javafx api or some other type of api. I have worked on printing system with javafx and also worked on simple jasperreport reporting system. I found `JasperReport` is very useful for report generating and documentation so i have suggested jasperviewerfx for the javafx version of jasperreport.

Comment: No problem for communication, So you say that the JavaFX print API doesn't differ printers. I'll try that, soon I'm going to try programming using that printer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to using `JasperReport` I'll try it if I needed it. but till now, it seems to be not needed, Thanks again for you suggestion.